# How are the letters deleted from this "Vowel eater"?

Tags: python

```
word = input("enter a word: ")
word = word.upper()


for letter in word:
    if letter == "A":
        continue
    elif letter == "E":
        continue
    elif letter == "I":
        continue
    elif letter =="O":
        continue
    elif letter == "U":
        continue
    else:
        print(letter)
```

If I used Joseph as an example, it would return JSPH but I have no idea how the vowels are "deleted"

Comment: You will need to learn what `continue` does in a loop.

Comment: The vowels aren't "deleted". They are just not printed.

Comment: "*I have no idea*" : Then now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger. You need to learn how your code runs line-by-line, and that's usually done with a debugger or even by going through your code with a pen and paper. It will be difficult for you to keep asking people on the internet to explain codes for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `continue`, it essentially skips to the end of the loop and starts the next loop, so following through your loop:

1. Look at the current letter
2. If the current letter is a vowel, then `continue`. (This skips to the next letter in the loop, so the line `print(letter)` will not be run).
3. If the current letter is *not* a vowel, it reaches the `else` statement and prints the letter.

This means that in the end, the program only prints letters which are *not* vowels, as whenever a vowel is reached `continue` is run meaning it skips to the next letter (so the letter is not printed).

Side note: even if you didn't use `continue` in each `elif` statement, and used maybe `pass` instead (which is just a "blank" instruction), the code would still work as by entering one of the `if` or `elif` options in the `if` statement, it means that it won't run any of the other `elif` or `else`s afterwards, so the `print(letter)` wouldn't be called either way. A better way to show the use of `continue` would be to place the `print(letter)` outside and after the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

The letter variable takes one character from the input and compares using the if-else statement. If the character matches the vowels the letter is not printed.

That means the program is only printing the non-vowel characters.

Answer (score -1):

Use regex

```
word = input("enter a word: ")
word = word.upper()

import re
re.sub("[AEIOU]","", word)
```

Comment: The OP was not asking for code, but an explanation of the existing code.